# mkdir makes wrong directory names when used with cut on *.tex files

Tags: linux, bash, unix, latex, tex

When make directories for each file with certain extension:

```
    $ ls
    a.ttt  b.ttt  c.ttt  d.ttt  e.ttt
    $ mkdir $(ls *.ttt | cut -f 1 -d ".")
    $ ls
    a  a.ttt  b  b.ttt  c  c.ttt  d  d.ttt  e  e.ttt
```

...everything works just fine. However if I do it for .tex files I get following results:

```
    $ ls
    a.tex  b.tex  c.tex  d.tex  e.tex
    $ mkdir $(ls *.tex | cut -f 1 -d ".")
    $ ls
    ?[00;32mb  ?[00;32mc  ?[00;32md  ?[00;32me  ?[0m?[00;32ma  a.tex  b.tex  c.tex  d.tex  e.tex
```

I just wanted to clean my latex directory and I get weird directory names. Why is that and how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is error prone to use output from `ls` like this.

You can use:

```
# grab all *.tex files in an array
arr=(*.tex)

# replace part after DOT and create directories
mkdir -p "${arr[@]//.*}"
```